# Leaflet: how can I update content of popup by jQuery

Tags: leaflet, jquery, find

in my popup is a spinner with class=spinner and an empty container for addon informations.

1. I want to hide after successful ajax.
2. I want to add some html in a container.

I tried this:

```
~~~


    map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
        var marker = e.popup._source;
        $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
        $(e.popup).find('.spinner').hide();
        $(e.popup).find('container').html('same stuff')    

});
~~~
```

It doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
e.popup.setContent("content");
```

Works for me, using Leaflet 0.7.3.  Note that setContent() was added sometime in Leaflet 0.7.

Comment: This is the correct answer, [as demonstrated by a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/87r62qdw/). Click the icon to display a popup; then after a one-second delay, the popup content is modified by `e.popup.setContent()`.